# Python: Por qué se duplican mis ítem en una lista de listas?

Tags: python, array, lista

Se me duplican los ítems en la lista cuando estoy poniendo estos ítems en un lugar específicos, algún conocedor de mi error me quitaría mucha frustración :D

```py
x=int(input())
y=int(input())
L=[]
aux=[]
for i in range(x):
  aux.append('')
for j in range(y):
  L.append(aux)
print(L)
culo=[0,0,'a']
fila=culo[0]
col=culo[1]
obj=culo[2]
L[col][fila]=obj
print(L)
```

Comment: Cual es el resultado que esperas?? Cuales son los datos de entrada? Por favor añade más detalles a tu pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Si por "duplicar los items" te refieres que al cambiar un elemento de la lista (dentro de una lista de listas `L`) altera y cambia también a las otras listas, la razón es porque al definir `L.append(aux)`  estás creando una **referencia** a la lista `aux`, así que cada lista depende de `aux`. En tu código, al asignar un nuevo elemento con `L[col][fila]=obj` en el fondo estás alterando `aux` y por ende alterando cada una de las listas.

Si lo que quieres es que cada lista sea independiente y no sea una referencia a `aux` puedes usar [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html):

```py
import copy
x=int(input())
y=int(input())
L=[]
aux=[]
for i in range(x):
  aux.append('')
for j in range(y):
  L.append(copy.copy(aux))
```

Referencia. [python - List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Una sintaxis ligeramente más breve (y en mi opinión más legible) consiste en usar `aux.copy()` en lugar de `copy.copy(aux)`. Además eso evita el `import copy`